# Logstash substring a field using position using mutate

Tags: logstash, logstash-filter

I wonder if there is a way of using a substring when using `add_field` in mutate filter, maybe with %{field} syntax.
For example:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "shorter_field" => "%{field[0:4]}" }
    }
}
```

I saw solutions using ruby filters, but I prefer only using mutate because I have a sequence of operation I'm doing using the filter and I prefer keeping it simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

(assuming that you need first 4 characters of the field.)

**CODE:**

```
filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => ["shorter_field", "(?<=^....)(.*)", ""]
    }
}
```

In here all characters except first 4 characters will be removed from `shorter_field`.

example:

**INPUT:**

```
shorter_field = example_value
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
shorter_field = exam
```